# SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty when I set LANGUAGES

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

**Hi here is the error**

*raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.*

**when I remove LANGUAGES from settings file, Then Its running , other wise giving the error, I tried but not able to resolve it please help.**

**Code Structure - config-settings-base.py, local.py, production.py.
I set LANGUAGES in base.py. here is the code of base.py setting**

````
```


 import os
    from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
    import environ
    from django.urls import reverse_lazy


    env = environ.Env()
    ROOT_DIR = environ.Path(__file__) - 3
    APPS_DIR = ROOT_DIR.path('userpeek')
    READ_DOT_ENV_FILE = env.bool('DJANGO_READ_DOT_ENV_FILE', default=True)
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'tango_with_django.settings')
    if READ_DOT_ENV_FILE:
        # OS environment variables take precedence over variables from .env
        env_file = str(ROOT_DIR.path('.env'))
        env.read_env(env_file)
    ENV = env
    application_name = env('APPLICATION_NAME')
    LOG_DIR = env('LOG_DIR')
    FILE = application_name + '.log'

    DEBUG = env.bool('DJANGO_DEBUG', False)
    # Local time zone. Choices are
    # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
    # though not all of them may be available with every OS.
    # In Windows, this must be set to your system time zone.

    # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!

    USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True

    # DATABASES
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    # DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['manager.router.DatabaseAppsRouter']
    # DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['klm.application.router.FailoverRouter']
    DATABASES = {
        # 'default': {
        #     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        #     'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        # }
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': env('DB_NAME'),
            'HOST': env('DB_HOST'),
            'PORT': env('DB_PORT', cast=int),
            'USER': env('DB_USER'),
            'PASSWORD': env('DB_PASSWORD'),
        }
    }

    # URLS
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#root-urlconf
    ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#wsgi-application
    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'

    # APPS
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    # STATIC FILE CONFIGURATION
    TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#site-id
    SITE_ID = 1
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-i18n
    USE_I18N = True
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-l10n
    USE_L10N = True
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-tz
    USE_TZ = True
    #
    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es'

    LANGUAGES = (
        ('en', _('English')),
        ('es', _('Spanish')),

    )
    LOCALE_PATHS = (
        os.path.join(str(ROOT_DIR), 'locale'),
    )
    print(LOCALE_PATHS)

    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#installed-apps
    # PROJECT_APPS = env.list('PROJECT_APPS')
    # THIRD_PARTY_APPS = env.list('THIRD_PARTY_APPS')
    # REST_FRAME_WORK_APPS = env.list('REST_FRAME_WORK_APPS')
    # ALL_AUTH_APPS = env.list('ALL_AUTH_APPS')
    # INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + \
    # REST_FRAME_WORK_APPS + ALL_AUTH_APPS + PROJECT_APPS

    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'corsheaders',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'crispy_forms',
        'compressor',
        'chargeover',
        'rest_framework',
        'rest_framework.authtoken',
        'django.contrib.sites',
        'user',
        'profile',
        'subscriptions',
        'test',
    ]
    # middleware classes we can add custom classes here also

    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
        # 'django.middleware.common.BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware', # to mail admin when error comes
        'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'corsheaders.middleware.CorsPostCsrfMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
        # 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
        # 'user.custom_middleware.middleware.RefreshTokenMiddleware',
    ]


    # CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
    # #
    # CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    #     "http://localhost:4200",
    # ]

    # A list of HTTP verbs that are allowed for the actual request. Defaults to:
    CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
    CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
    CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = env.list('CORS_ALLOW_METHODS')
    CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = env.list('CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS')


    # auth password validation handler

    AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
        },
    ]


    # rest_framework pemission and authentication classes handler

    REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        # 'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'rest_framework.views.exception_handler',
        'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
            'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
            # 'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
            'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',

        ],
        'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
            'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        ],
    }


    # add custom register serializer
    # REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
    #     'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'user.serializer.CustomRegisterSerializer',
    # }
    AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
        # 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
        'user.authentication.login_authentication.EmailBackend',
    ]
    # AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    #     # default
    #     'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    #     # email login
    #     'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
    # )
    # User Account handle configuration
    """     singup email confirmation       """
    ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
    ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
    ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "email"
    ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = True
    # ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
    # ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True

    # after click on link of registation this will be redirect
    # ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_ANONYMOUS_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('account_confirm_complete')
    # ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('account_confirm_complete')
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/
    MEDIA_ROOT = str(ROOT_DIR('media'))
    COMPRESS_ENABLED = os.environ.get('COMPRESS_ENABLED', False)
    # See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-url
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    # Static file Setup
    STATIC_ROOT = str(ROOT_DIR('static'))

    # See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-url
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    # See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        str(ROOT_DIR.path('staticfiles')),
    ]

    # See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-finders
    STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
        'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
    ]
    ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = env('ACCOUNT_ADAPTER')
    URL_FRONT = env('URL_FRONT')
    # TEMPLATES
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#templates
    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES-BACKEND
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-dirs
            'DIRS': [
                str(APPS_DIR.path('templates')),
            ],
            'OPTIONS': {
                # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-debug
                'debug': DEBUG,
                # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-loaders
                # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#loader-types
                'loaders': [
                    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
                ],
                # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-context-processors
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                    'django.template.context_processors.media',
                    'django.template.context_processors.static',
                    'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]

    # http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#template-packs
    CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

    # FIXTURES
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#fixture-dirs
    # FIXTURE_DIRS = (
    #     str(APPS_DIR.path('fixtures')),
    # )

    # EMAIL
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-backend
    EMAIL_BACKEND = env('DJANGO_EMAIL_BACKEND', default='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend')

    # ADMIN
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Django Admin URL.
    ADMIN_URL = 'admin/'
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#admins
    ADMINS = [
        ("""Rahul Kumar""", 'rahul.kumar2@wildnettechnologies'),
    ]
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#managers
    MANAGERS = ADMINS

    """     Session management       """
    SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = env('SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE')
    SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = int(env('SESSION_COOKIE_AGE'))
    SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = env('SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST')
    # Your stuff...
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ```

    And here is local.py

    ```from .base import *  # noqa
    from .base import env

    # GENERAL
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#debug
    DEBUG = env.bool('DJANGO_DEBUG', default=False)
    TEMPLATES[0]['OPTIONS']['debug'] = DEBUG
    ENV = env
    SECRET_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secret-key
    # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!

    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = env.list('ALLOWED_HOSTS')
    INSTALLED_APPS += ['django_extensions']
    # CACHES
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#caches
    CACHES = {
        'default': {
            'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
            'LOCATION': ''
        }
    }

    # TEMPLATES
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#templates
    TEMPLATES[0]['OPTIONS']['debug'] = DEBUG  # noqa F405

    # EMAIL
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-backend
    DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = env('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
    EMAIL_BACKEND = env('DJANGO_EMAIL_BACKEND')
    EMAIL_HOST = env('EMAIL_HOST')
    EMAIL_PORT = int(env('EMAIL_PORT'))
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = env('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = env('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
    SITE_ID = env('SITE_ID')
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = env('EMAIL_USE_TLS')

    # django-debug-toolbar
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#prerequisites
    # https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#middleware
    # MIDDLEWARE += ['debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware']  # noqa F405
    # https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#debug-toolbar-config


    # django-extensions
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation_instructions.html#configuration


    # Your stuff...
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    LOGGING = {
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': False,
        'filters': {
            'require_debug_false': {
                '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
            }
        },
        'formatters': {
            'verbose': {
                'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s '
                          '%(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
            },
        },
        'handlers': {
            # 'mail_admins': {
            #     'level': 'ERROR',
            #     'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            #     'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
            # },
            'console': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'formatter': 'verbose',
            },
            'file': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'filename': os.path.join(LOG_DIR, FILE),
                'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
                'formatter': 'verbose'
            },
            'applogfile': {
                'level': 'INFO',
                'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
                'filename': os.path.join(LOG_DIR, FILE),
                'formatter': 'verbose'
            },
        },
        'loggers': {
            'django.request': {
                'handlers': ['applogfile', 'file'],
                'level': 'ERROR',
                'propagate': True
            },
            'django.security.DisallowedHost': {
                'level': 'ERROR',
                'handlers': [],
                'propagate': False
            },
            'user': {
                'handlers': ['applogfile', 'file'],
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'propagate': True,
            },
            'profile': {
                'handlers': ['applogfile', 'file'],
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'propagate': True,
            },
        },
        'test': {
            'handlers': ['applogfile', 'file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'accounts': {
            'handlers': ['applogfile', 'file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },

    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issues by creating a new secret key.
Thank you all